# Model training in python and running model in Golang, problem during import of the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, go, tensorflow2.0

I installed the last version of TensorFlow (2.3) and under Python, it's running fine but under Golang I got an exception:

> ... but does not contain package github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core/protobuf/for_core_protos_go_proto

I got TensorFlow to work with Golang by changing the version to 1.15.0

Now, I'm facing the following problem:

**Python code with TensorFlow 2.3**

```py
import tensorflow as tf
    
df = pd.read_csv(data_path, sep=';')
X = df[df.columns[:8]]
y = df[df.columns[8:-1]]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3)
    
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu', name="inputNode"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, name="inferNode"))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=500)
    
tf.keras.models.save_model(model=model, filepath='./', save_format='tf')
```

**Golang code with TensorFlow 1.15.0**

```golang
model, err := tf.LoadSavedModel("./", []string{"serve"}, nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error loading saved model: %s\n", err.Error())
    return
}
defer model.Session.Close()
data := [][]float32{make([]float32, 8)}
data[0][0] = 1.0
data[0][1] = 1.0
data[0][2] = 1.0
data[0][3] = 1.0
data[0][4] = 1.0
data[0][5] = 1.0
data[0][6] = 1.0
data[0][7] = 1.0
tensor, _ := tf.NewTensor(data)
   
result, err := model.Session.Run(
    map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
        model.Graph.Operation("inputNode_input").Output(0): tensor, // Replace this with your input layer name
    },
    []tf.Output{
        model.Graph.Operation("inferNode").Output(0), // Replace this with your output layer name
    },
    nil,
)
    
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error running the session with input, err: %s\n", err.Error())
    return
}
    
fmt.Printf("Result value: %v \n", result[0].Value())
```

The golang throws this exception:

```
-- FAIL: TestMlPredict (6.93s)
panic: nil-Operation. If the Output was created with a Scope object, see Scope.Err() for details. [recovered]
    panic: nil-Operation. If the Output was created with a Scope object, see Scope.Err() for details.
```

Here an example feature vector

```
header:   20         15           10          5           0       branch1   branch2     branch3     output1     output2     output3     
data:   2.518878    3.778791    5.021497    5.559673    5.402780    0.0     0.109421    0.109253    0.0            0.0       1.0
```

What am I doing wrong? The input and output names should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

I actually fixed the fist problem in a fork of TensorFlow I maintain, that contains all the compiled protobufs. The fork is a dependency of the package [`galeone/tfgo`](https://github.com/galeone/tfgo) and it get's automatically downloaded using `go mod`.

You try

```
go get github.com/galeone/tfgo
```

And you'll be able to use the tensorflow/go and tensorflow/op packages + all the additions of tfgo.

Answer (score 0):

The operation names were wrong. What I did to find out these names? I executed the cli command:
`saved_model_cli show --dir ./ --all`

And what about golang and tensorflow 2.3? please check the issue: [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41808)
and
readMe: [readme](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/go/README.md)